# Multiple sortable lists with jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am building a todo list application for one of my projects and I am creating multiple todo lists dynamically from the database and each todo list will have multiple todo items.  The items will be constrained to their own list and will not be able to be connected to another list.

I've done a single sortable list in jquery before, but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to write DRY code, so I am not repeating myself for each new todo list a user creates.  Since the jquery code will have to figure out how many todo lists there are, and then manage each one.

Anybody know how to go about doing this or could you talk through it with some pseudocode or an example would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with using the jQuery [sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable) plugin and just doing something like

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('ol, ul').sortable(); //make every ordered and unordered list sortable
});
```

Comment: good call, then I can just grab the id of ul so I know the parent...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

two other options (in general):

1. create the sortable group by id:

   ```
   $("#list1, #list2, #list3").sortable({ connectWith: "#list1, #list2, #list3" });
   ```
2. create the sortable group by class:

   ```
   $("#list1, #list2, #list3").sortable({ connectWith: ".transfer" });
   ```

   (`.transfer` is the class, just assign this to all your lists in your html.)

Answer (score 0):

To be DRY in jQuery, you want to [write plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), or use an existing plugin such as [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but using Tablesorter has nothing to do with my question does it?  

I agree a plugin, would be a nice solution, but I am looking for how I should write it.

Comment: perhaps you could provide more information.  It sounded like you were looking to do multiple sortable todo lists.   A few people thought that you were looking for a sortable solution.